# Is there a valid Gemfile for Rails 3.1 together with Scss, Haml, Compass and HTML-Boilerplate in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, compass-sass, html5boilerplate

I have a successful Rails 3.0.x project with the following subset of Gems in the Gemfile:

```
gem "compass"
gem "haml"
gem "haml-rails"
gem "html5-boilerplate"
```

I tried today to upgrade to Rails 3.1 and keep all functionality, and had numerous problems in doing so. I did not yet find a configuration that did work for me in production mode, so I am working now with developing mode.

I followed the following advices here:

- ["Upgrading to Rails 3.1"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1) from Railscast: very good as usual, and told me how to change `production.rb`, `development.rb` and `application.rb` to update the configuration for the asset pipeline. But did not touch compass, sass, and html5-boilerplate.
- ["Setup html-boilerplate with Rails 3.1"](http://kucaahbe.github.com/2011/08/30/html5-boilerplate-and-rails3.1.html) That contained the best fit for me, but does not work, because the method `ie_html` is not available in production mode. The change in the Gemfile is noted down
- ["Unable to get Rails 3.1, Compass, Sass, Blueprint working on Heroku Cedar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311000/unable-to-get-rails-3-1-compass-sass-blueprint-working-on-heroku-cedar) This did not work for me at all, I had problems to the the assets compiled then. There the try was to have everything global, because there is a dependency between Compass and Html-Boilerplate, and Html-Boilerplate has to be global due to the method `ie_html`.
- Every try to use only some the Gems in the `group :assets` block was not successful. Most of the time, the dependency between e.g. compass and sass, or compass and html5-boilerplate could not be fulfilled.

So my question is: Is there a working Gemfile which allows to use Haml, Sass, Compass, Html5-Boilerplate and of course Rails 3.1 together?

New Gemfile working in development mode, but not in production mode:

```
gem "haml-rails"
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.alpha.0'
  gem "html5-boilerplate"
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

I have tried to create a fresh Rails 3.1 application, and added there an image resource. There everything is working fine, so no difference between development mode and production mode. In my migrated application, I have now the following state:

- Works well in development mode.
- Disable some of the html5-boilerplate things to work around the problems in production.
- Does not find yet the precompiled images in production mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First my apologies for adding another answer, but I think the history is helpful for others.

I tried again (thank's to the comment of @theanym) to create a new application with rails 3.1.1, html5-boilerplate, compass, sass and haml, and I found a working solution for development and production mode.

These are the steps I have taken:

1. I started with a new application and followed there the recipe ["Setup html5-boilerplate with Rails 3.1"](http://kucaahbe.github.com/2011/08/30/html5-boilerplate-and-rails3.1.html).
2. When I started the application (in development mode), it worked nicely.
3. When I started then in production mode, I got the following error:

   ```
   c:\apps\ruby\rails3\not>rails s -e production
   C:/apps/ruby/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/html5-boilerplate-1.0.0/lib/html5-boilerplate.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': 
     uninitialized constant Object::Compass (NameError)
       from C:/apps/ruby/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
   ```
4. I then changed the `Gemfile` (only the relevant part):

   ```
   group :assets do
     gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
     gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
     gem "compass", '~> 0.12.alpha.0', :group => :production
     gem 'html5-boilerplate', :group => :production
     gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
   end
   ```

The relevant part of the solution for me was to denote for `compass` and `html5-boilerplate` that additional argument `:group => :production`.

I then had to precompile the assets, and had to change `style.scss` to `style.css.scss`, but that was a minor tweak. Tested the application both with development and production mode, and there seems to be no error.

Answer (score 2):

I have it working on Heroku Cedar.

```
gem "rails", "~> 3.1.0"
gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0"

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.alpha.0'
  gem 'html5-boilerplate'
end
```

But before `git push heroku` first precompile locally with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

then add all public/assets to your git repo and commit. Then:

```
git push heroku master
```

Heroku will detect the `public/assets/manifest.yml` file and just use these files.

This works for me so should work! Cheers

Comment: First of all, thank's a lot for your reply! I think your problem is different to mine, I don't use Heroku. My problem is that parts of the HTML mode use helper methods that are provided by html5-boilerplate, and this code is not available in production mode. So the problem was not with the assets, but with the ruby code used in the html5-boilerplate templates.

Comment: See my other answer. I hope this will work now for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just to include some of the information that may others help, here my current situation that works (more or less):

- I have defined the `Gemfile` like defined in the question.
- Therefore I had to ensure that the html5-boilerplate is *not* used in production mode. I have commented out parts of the html code that I do not need. I use the html5-boilerplate templates (mostly), and the application is on my local PC only, so the performance gain by using e.g. jquery from Google is not so relevant for me.
- Solved: The problems with the images in production mode (see one problem I could not solve currently at [How do I use reference images in Sass when using Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393315/how-do-i-use-reference-images-in-sass-when-using-rails-3-1), and the [Rails 3.1.0 - asset:precompile fails when using asset_url() SASS function](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2765) which is not solved in Rails 3.1.0)) where configuration problems due to the migration of Rails 3.0.x app to Rails 3.1.0. I solved it by copying a working configuration of a new created app (mostly `production.rb` which contained the wrong entry).

I will not invest more time here, and wait for updates for Rails 3.1.1 and html5-boilerplate.

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution? I was able to use the haml-rails, compass, html5-boilerplate, and compass-960-plugin gems perfectly for a Rails 3.0.x app, but haven't found a good alternative for 3.1.x. Any suggestions / pointers would be appreciated.